# Using keras in the datalab has issue

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I am having trouble with using keras in the datalab. Setting is (us-east-1, n1-standard-1).

The issue comes when import Keras then try to use the pre-trained model like vgg16.
It seems the future package or the h5py package has issue but not clear how to efficiently fix this within datalab's setting.

Simply re-install keras with its dependencies (h5py, yaml...) doesn't solve the issue.

Any opinion will be very helpful!
Thanks.